# Split not working in javascript ,Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me why `if condition` in this code isn't working?

```
        var zaposleni=[];
        for(i=1;i<brOpcija;i++){
        zaposleni.push(myOpts[i].value);
        }

        var zaposleniRestoran=[];
        for(i=1;i<brOpcija;i++){

            if(zaposleni[i].split(' ').slice(2).join(' ') == vrednostSelekta()){
                zaposleniRestoran.push(zaposleni[i].split(' ').slice(0,2));
            }
        }
```

Here,i have array `zaposleni` where i push some values,and array is look like `["name" "surname" "restaurantName"]`,and then i am checking if `restaurantName == vrednostSelekta()` (where `vrednostSelekta()` is return value of some function in javascript),but i always get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (zaposleni.js:51)
    at HTMLSelectElement.handle (jquery.min.js:55)
    at HTMLSelectElement.o (jquery.min.js:49)
```

But when i erase this if,and then type that in debugger,i get no error and it is working there..Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I know every array for lop should start with i=0; because every array first 'item' has index 0, if you have one 'item' in array 1<1 is not true so it will return false. By your language I should say "zagrej malo stolicu to su osnovne stvari".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the "zaposleni" array is empty or maybe there is only one element in it. Your for loop is starting at "i=1".

Answer (score 1):

In the error, `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` means that you're calling `.split(...)` to something that isn't defined.

This means that at the beginning of the if, the script is stopping when `zaposleni[i]` is not defined.

This is probably because `i` is bigger than the length of `zaposleni` at the biggest value for `i`, as you're iterating up to the same value, but you're starting to push at `i=1` rather than `i=0`, as array indices in JS start at `0`. In other words, you're adding a value at `zaposleni[0]`, not `zaposleni[last index value]`, and requiring from `zaposleni[1]` up to `zaposleni[last index value]`, so the last one will be undefined.

The issue may also be that `myOpts[i].value` is probably undefined for some values of `i`, so I would recommend checking that